# Remove "." from filename in bash

Tags: bash, git-bash

I have a bunch of folders which look like the below, I need to remove the point between the 2.0:

```
0010_DWI_MS_2.0_first_2874028735_10.bvec
0010_DWI_MS_2.0_first_2874028735_10.bval
0010_DWI_MS_2.0_first_2874028735_10.nii
0011_DWI_MS_2.0_first_2874028735_11.bvec
0011_DWI_MS_2.0_first_2874028735_11.bval
0011_DWI_MS_2.0_first_2874028735_11.nii
```

What I'm trying to acheive:

```
0010_DWI_MS_20_first_2874028735_10.bvec
0010_DWI_MS_20_first_2874028735_10.bval
0010_DWI_MS_20_first_2874028735_10.nii
0011_DWI_MS_20_first_2874028735_11.bvec
0011_DWI_MS_20_first_2874028735_11.bval
0011_DWI_MS_20_first_2874028735_11.nii
```

Is there also a way to do this for folders rather than files?

Comment: Renaming is the same for files and folders. You should be able to do this using the `rename` command.

Comment: `for d in LIST; do mv "$d" "${d/2.0/20}"; done` where `LIST` is your list of directories or a glob pattern that catches them all (e.g., `001[01]_DWI_MS_2.0_first*`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this solution:

```
for d in *2.0*/; do mv "$d" "${d/2.0/20}"; done
```

This will move only directories containing `2.0` in their names.

Answer (score 0):

A `sed` approach that removes the first <kbd>.</kbd> it encounters.

```
$ for i in "0010_DWI_MS_2.0_first_2874028735_10.bvec";do 
  echo "${i}" | sed -e 's/\.//'
done
0010_DWI_MS_20_first_2874028735_10.bvec
```